# can i access an element within a view, with only access to the view's reference variable?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

If I have a view - `myCoolView` - and I'd like to change the text of a button in the view, how do I do it?

Given that I know that the button is called, say, `myCoolButton`, and it was added to the view in some function, and now, in a different function I have access to `myCoolView`, how do I change the button text?

I checked the Titanium API and I cannot see a "getter" call on a view to access anything that was added to it via the `add` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "children" property, [as documented](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-children).

```
// Create the views.
var myCoolView = Ti.UI.createView();
var myCoolButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'My Cool Button',
    id: 'myButtonsID'
});
myCoolView.add(myCoolButton);

// Later, find the button.
var children = myCoolView.children;
if (children) {
    for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (children[i].id === 'myButtonsID') {
            children[i].title = 'My Updated Cool Button';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: huh. So there's no "direct" way? Would it be simpler just to keep a global (for the js file, anyway) variable around that pointed to the name "myCoolButton"?

Comment: No. There is no DOM. These are just plain old JavaScript objects. It would be better to keep a reference around, if you need it. Or if you're creating this in a utility function of some sort, return a composed object, such as { view: view, button: button }, so that you can reference the button easily, and add the view to whatever existing hierarchy you have.